# Remove Hebrew from my computer

Tags: windows

I accidentally installed Hebrew on my computer and now I can't read menus and everything is right to left.

How do I remove Hebrew from my Windows on my PC?

Answer (score 2):

Open an elevated Command Prompt (cmd), and enter the following command:

```
Lpksetup /u
```

The Install or Uninstall display languages panel will open.

Select the Hebrew language, click on *Next* and the Language Interface Pack
will start uninstalling. You will then be asked to restart your computer.

If you have difficulties typing in English, the upper-case letters
are English on the Hebrew keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm unable to use it as ALL of the text on my computer is now in Hebrew and I can't read it in order to follow your steps.

Comment: Nice situation... Try to type Win+R, enter in upper-case CMD, then Ctrl+Shift+OK, then follow the above, all in upper-case.